# Iterate Through Custom LinkedList Class of Objects

Tags: java, linked-list, iteration

I have created my own `LinkedList` class and created a `LinkedList` that will contain object Song (contains title, artist, album, length). The error I am having is that when trying to iterate through the list I am getting the "Can only iterate over array of java.lang.Iterable." I think my issue is that I am iterating over the class instance and therefore am missing something in my linked list class to be able to do this type of iteration. Not to sure what I need to add though, thanks in advance.

**Here is where I try to iterate:**

```
System.out.print("Enter song title: ");
String searchTitle = input.nextLine();
for ( Song i : list ){
    if ( i.getTitle() == searchTitle ){
        System.out.println(i);
        found = true;
    }
}
if ( found != true ){
    System.out.println("Song does not exist.");
}
```

**My LinkedList Class**

```
public class LinkedList {

private Node first;

private Node last;

public LinkedList(){
    first = null;
    last = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return first == null;
}

public int size(){
    int count = 0;
    Node p = first;
    while( p != null ){
        count++;
        p = p.getNext();
    }
    return count;
}

public Node get( int i ){
    Node prev = first;
    for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){
        prev = prev.getNext();
}
    return prev;
}

public String toString(){
    String str = "";
    Node n = first;
    while( n != null ){
        str = str + n.getValue() + " ";
         n = n.getNext();
    }
    return str;
}

public void add( Song c ){
    if( isEmpty() ) {
        first = new Node(c);
        last = first;
    }else{
        Node n = new Node(c);
        last.setNext(n);
        last = n;
    }
}
```

**Song Class**

```
public class Song {

    private String title;

    private String artist;

    private String album;

    private String length;

    private static int songCounter = 0;

    public Song(String title, String artist, String album, String length){
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.album = album;
        this.length = length;
        songCounter++;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getArtist(){
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getAlbum(){
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album){
        this.album = album;
    }

    public String getLength(){
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(String length){
        this.length = length;
    }

    public static int getSongCounter(){
        return songCounter;
    }

    public int compareArtist(Song o){
        return artist.compareTo(o.artist);
    }

    public int compareTitle(Song o){
        return title.compareTo(o.title);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return title +","+artist+","+album+","+length;
    }
```

Comment: Post your `Song` class.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard added Song class

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very explicit:

> Can only iterate over array of `java.lang.Iterable`.

This means that your class **must** implement the [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface.

For your case, the class that must implement this must be `LinkedList`:

```
public class LinkedList implements Iterable<Song> {
    //implement methods in Iterable interface
}
```

You may also *upgrade* your `LinkedList` implementation to handle a generic element rather than just `Song` object references.

Comment: Is there a way where i can iterate through my list differently where I wouldn't have to implement this?